# Why do I not see my /bin, /var, (etc.) directories in my root partition?

Tags: filesystem, directory, ls

I recently bought a VPS and when I log in as a root user, I dont see the /boot, /bin, /var, etc. directories. Why is this?

This is what I see when I use my `ls -la` command in the terminal. I am the root user and in the root directory:

[image: Output from "ls -la"]

Comment: Are you in the `/root` directory (the home directory of user `root`) or the *filesystem root* directory `/`? BTW there's no need to post screenshots for stuff like this: just copy/paste the terminal output as text.

Comment: Please add the output of `pwd` to your question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It appears that you are in the directory /root and not /. Please type:

```
cd /
ls -al
```

Comment: @ripjerry - it happens to the best of us :)

Comment: I cannot believe this! Thanks. I was wondering why I saw no directories when I telnet as a root on VPS too.